# Hitting Shift+Backspace in Vim for Powershell results in Îy character

Tags: microsoft-windows, powershell

I'm having an issue in Vim for powershell, installed with Chocolatey. Whenever I'm pressing shift and hit the backspace on my keyboard, it enters the characters `Îy`. I found a couple of related links which describe similar problems.

- [SE link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439970/shift-backspace-wont-work-on-vim-for-windows)
- [Reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/lyufrh/remapping_shiftbackspace_currently_getting/)

I tried adding `imap Îy <BS>` to my vimrc file, but the problem persists.

I would really like to find a solution to this problem as it is hurting my workflow. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `<C-v><Shift-BS>` insert (in insert mode)? That should insert the exact characters Vim receives, and *usually* you should be be able to map it; but I don't know much about Powershell or Windows.

Comment: I receive ``Îy`` for ``<C-v><S-BS>`` and ``îz`` for ``<C-v><C-BS>``

Comment: I created https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/10283 for this

Comment: Thanks for the pull request. To be complete we receive ``Îz`` for ``<C-v><C-BS>`` and ´´Î{`` for ``<C-v><M-BS>`` and ``\x88`` for ``<C-v><M-S-BS>``. Let us know when we can test your pull request.